# ¿Se puede esperar hasta que un boton se pulse en un JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

En mi código llamo a un JFrame desde un objeto llamado tablero de esta forma:

```
Coronar coro=new Coronar();
coro.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(coro.getDecision());
```

Lo que intento hacer es que el programa espere hasta que el usuario pulse el botón y me devuelva la decisión con una función que se encuentra en coronar como se muestra aquí:

```
public int decision=0;
private void jB_CaballoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    decision=1;
}                                          
private void jB_ArfilActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    decision=2;
}                                        
private void jB_DamaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    decision=3;
}                                       
private void jB_TorreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    decision=4;
} 
public int getDecision(){
return decision;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que el programa no espera hasta que el usuario oprima un botón sino que devuelve con lo que instancie la variable decisión ósea 0, como hago para esperar a la acción del botón y hay si retornar el dato. De antemano gracias

Comment: Con un centinela y un while, espero haberme explicado

Comment: Si, ya lo había intentado pero el JFrame no carga y el programa se queda bloqueado. Igualmente, Gracias